# How to achieve Incandescence with Cycles materials

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, light

Okay so heres the description of what i want i have created a logo in gimp exported its as scalable vector (svg) imported it to blender increaed the extrusion and bevel, and want it to have that look when metal is near ponit of melting but at the other end it shall already be cooleddown. heres a link to what Incandescence is from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescence

Comment: Something like this: http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/70363?

Comment: yeah "something" exactly something like tihs :D

Comment: You are welcome! Just for the community it would be nice to have an image of your issue. Can you update the question with an image if somebody else is searching for the same?

Comment: i Will when im done

Comment: Would you please add a little more content to the question? (i.e. an Image along with a description of incandescence, or a link to a Wikipedia page). It's automatically getting flagged for it's length.

Comment: okay i will the thing from blendswap didnt gave me those results i wanted to see. added the details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You coud mix a diffuse shader with an emission shader using a gradient ramp.

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks a bit like the german flag but thank you :D